# Get non-rendered content from WP-API

Tags: api, wp-api

I'd like to get the content of certain fields non-rendered, so for example get the excerpt text without WP adding the `<p></p>` tags. Is this possible without having to go into PHP, so just by settings or preferably using a param in the GET?

Comment: I'm a bit confused: when you say non-rendered content do you mean content that isn't already included on the web API? Or did you just mean to 'non-render' the wrapping <p> tags?

Comment: it's called 'rendered content' so I choose the opposite terminology, non-rendered. Maybe that's not correct but I indeed mean without WordPress adding the <p> tags and possibly other things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old post but I got the same issue today.
You need to add the parameters `&context=edit` in the api endpoint.

Comment: thanks! Feels a bit like a hack though